# Re-order close reasons, to discourage bad migrations

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-reasons

Currently the close reasons, in order, are:

- exact duplicate
- off-topic

  - off-topic expands to offer migration destinations
- not constructive
- not a real question
- too localized

It seems to me that this ordering encourages deciding what other sites a question is a good fit for, before deciding if it's even a real, constructive question.

I suggest that off-topic be moved *down* to encourage people to decide if a question is constructive or really a question before deciding that it's a potential migration target. Hopefully this would lead to fewer rejected migrations.

New order would be more like:

- exact duplicate
- not a real question
- not constructive
- off-topic

  - off-topic expands to offer migration destinations
- too localized

(I'm a little torn about whether off-topic belongs before or after too-localized. Definitely belongs after NC and NARQ, though)

Comment: Hmm, I would put Not a Real Question above Not Constructive though.

Comment: I like it, though I think I might put the off-topic last.

Comment: @animuson: You know, you're right. changed.

Comment: I would actually just kill the migration path [perhaps just to certain sites], people tend to be poor judges of what fits elsewhere. I wonder how many migrated questions just get downvoted and closed on the target sites. "Belongs on Programmers." No, it doesn't! It's either been asked a million times there as well or is just as non-constructive or localized there as it is on SO. *Suggest* that it might be better received elsewhere, but put the onus on the original user to actually do the research and make it happen.

Comment: I would rather put "exact duplicate" to the last place, as closing a question as exact duplicate of another question that is too localized, or off-topic makes few sense, to me. The question is then, are we sure the closing reasons are not already ordered in the way they should be evaluated?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram If you make that into a Meta Question, I'll upvote and spam everyone on Programmers to support en masse.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: I can see the argument, but moving migration down the list is less controversial than killing migration. Make that a separate question.

Comment: @Zaphod, ha! I'll let the more experienced and active users of Programmers touch that particular third rail. I'll just rant, rave, and shake my cane from a comfortable distance.

Comment: @Anthony: Don't hit any little kids with it, they're innocent! Also, the paper boy is off limits! He doesn't like you that way!

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I thought exact duplicate still belonged at the top, because it can be a duplicate of a closed question and saying something duplicates something else is easy. If it's a duplicate of a not-real or not-constructive question, the original should be closed (and maybe deleted).

Comment: Before I even click on "Close", I already know what I'll vote for(at least for off-topic votes). Reordering wouldn't help at all.

Comment: @freiheit The problem is that questions that are not duplicates can be deleted; if you, for example, close a question as duplicate of a question that is too localized, or off-topic, the link to the duplicated question could take to a question that only 10k users can see. I think that the link to the duplicated question should take to a question for which the user can add an answer, or to an active question (for which users can add a new answer when necessary); that doesn't happen with already closed questions.

Comment: I proposed something similar on EL&U, but the answers made me reconsider it... You just close a question according to the reason that fits best, not in a certain order.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I'm pretty sure we've already tripped over that rail many times. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you might as well put "too localized" before "off topic".  Here "off topic"
is a catch-all for all other reasons why a particular question doesn't belong on a particular
  site (though some questions closed as "exact duplicate" arguably do).  Only then can you
    decide to apply the "belongs on..." close reason and re-evaluate the five close reasons to
  that site to decide how to migrate.  So the workflow becomes:

- Exact duplicate on Stack Overflow?
- Not a real question?
- Not constructive on Stack Overflow?
- Too localized?
- Off topic on Stack Overflow?

  - If so, maybe it belongs on, say, Stack Exchange Site A.  Not constructive on Site A? (Some sites may have a different policy on constructive questions than others.)
  - Off topic on Site A?
  - If the test passes, migrate to Site A
  - .. and so on for Sites B and C (if necessary: only sites that make sense for the question
      must be considered) ..

Looking at the comments I will suggest this as merely a workflow preference, not a suggestion that the close reasons should indeed be reordered.

Comment: There's nothing especially notable about Programmers.SE in this context. Programmers.SE was originally billed as "Not Programming Related," but that's not the case anymore. Programmers.SE is a site in its own right, not a diversion for questions that are too subjective for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I was just using Programmers as an example.  Not all off-topic questions need to be migrated to Programmers, but others may be a good fit for Webmasters, Android Enthusiasts, or other sites. It definitely depends on the question.

Comment: Your new work flow for migrations has too many moving parts. I don't think it's fair to expect most users to check for duplicates on the target site before migrating, and "Not a Real Question" should already be established before migration is considered (NaRQ is not site-specific).