# What is the encouraged rank of close reasons?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

My question is *not* the same as [Priority of Close Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39658/priority-of-close-votes). I'm not asking about automated system behavior.

---

Consider the following hypothetical questions being posted on, e.g., Stack Overflow:

1. Which car over there best matches my eyes? (broad, local, nonconstructive, off topic)
2. Help my facebook is broken it wast yesterday? (broad, off topic, local)
3. How can I make my programmers stop putting gum in my hair? (local, nonconstructive)

When I inevitably go to close such questions, I'm not sure what reason to select: is it more *off topic* than *overly broad*? Is it more *localized* than *not constructive*?

Perhaps *off topic* gets priority because the OP *could fix* localized and broad issues, but not the topic? On the other hand, [we don't want to migrate bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119374/re-order-close-reasons-to-discourage-bad-migrations).

When a question qualifies for multiple reasons to close, which reasons should get priority? In what order should priority be distributed?

Comment: But, but, which car over there best matches my eyes *as a programmer*?

Comment: @Pekka - pretty sure that one belongs on Programmers :-D

Comment: You don't have *have* to choose a migration destination when selecting "off topic".  Moderators close as "off topic" all the time without migrating because we don't want to migrate crap.

Comment: Where can I ask the gum-in-hair question then? Because these programmers are really starting to piss me off!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For incredibly useless questions like your hypotheticals, I would say it doesn't matter.  Just pick one, and get it out—**GET IT OUT**.

I think the only time it might matter is if the question is in that narrow range whereby it's too non-constructive for Stack Overflow, but it would fit in Programmers.StackExchange without the people there throwing a fit.  If that's the case, I would say choose Off Topic, and vote to migrate accordingly.

Comment: I would say OP's question #3 would have been a _perfect_ fit for P.SE.. given all the subjective crap they entertain :)  [_ducks and takes cover_]

Comment: @Marvin - I'm glad I'm not going crazy (yet).  Every time I browse to PSE to kill 5 minutes, I see subjective crap littering the front page (all of which upvoted).  And then they throw tantrums when we migrate our subjective crap over there.  `</rant>`

Comment: Like this [gem](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132504/interviewer-question-what-is-the-greatest-strength-and-weakness-of-your-develop)

Comment: Yep, and the fact that stuff like [this](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2958/44303) is still entertained doesn't help. Anyway, I'm glad it's not our problem.